# Evaluate the double integral.

Tags: calculus

> To find:

$$\iint_R(x^2-xy)dA$$

> enclosed by

$$y=x, y=3x-x^2,$$

$$x=3x-x^2,$$

$$x=0, x=2,$$

$$y=0, y=2,$$

$$R=((x,y): 0\le x\le 2), (x \le y \le 3x-x^2)$$

$$\int_0^2\int_x^{3x-x^2}(x^2-xy)\,dy\,dx$$

$$\int_0^2 \left. \left(x^2y-x\frac{y^2}{2}\right) \right|_x^{3x-x^2}\,dx$$

> where to from here?

Comment: Could you rewrite properly the definition of $R$. @MMM and I offered you two different solutions because we read your text in different ways.

Comment: @Guilherme Thompson - the exact wording was "R is the region enclosed by $y=x$ and $y=3x-x^2$."

Comment: And how about the other equations,
$$x=3x−x^2, \tag{I}$$
$$x=0,x=2,\tag{II}$$
$$y=0,y=2\tag{III}$$

??? Also, what did you mean with $\mathrm{(I)}$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the change of variables $u=x$ and $v=y-x$, that is $x=u$ and $y=v-u$,  we have the Jacobian $\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right|=1$; from $0\le x\le 2$ we have $0\le u\le 2$ and from $x\le y\le 3x-x^2$, we have $0\le y-x\le 2x-x^2$ we have $0\le v\le 2u-u^2$. The integral becomes
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^2\int_0^{(2-u)u} (-uv)\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du\\
&=\int_0^2 (-u)\,\frac{u^2(2-u)^2}{2} \mathrm du=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2(4u^3-4u^4+u^5)\,\mathrm du\\
&=\left.-\frac{1}{2}\left(4u^4-\frac{4u^5}{5}+\frac{u^6}{6}\right)\right|_0^2=-\frac{2^4}{2}\left(4-\frac{4\cdot 2}{5}+\frac{2^2}{6}\right)=-\frac{8}{15}
\end{align}
Check with [WolframAlpha](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E2%5Cint_x%5E%7B3x-x%5E2%7D%28x%5E2-xy%29%5C,dy%5C,dx)

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{2}\!\int_{x}^{-{x}^{2}+3\,x}\!{x}^{2}-xy\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\!\int_{x}^{-{x}^{2}+3\,x}\!{x}^{2}\,{\rm d}y+\int_{x}^{-{
x}^{2}+3\,x}\!-xy\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{2} \left( -{x}^{2}+3\,x \right) -{x}^{3}+\int_{x}^{
-{x}^{2}+3\,x}\!-xy\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{2} \left( -{x}^{2}+3\,x \right) -{x}^{3}-x\int_{x}^
{-{x}^{2}+3\,x}\!y\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{2} \left( -{x}^{2}+3\,x \right) -{x}^{3}-x \left( 1
/2\, \left( -{x}^{2}+3\,x \right) ^{2}-1/2\,{x}^{2} \right) \,{\rm d}x
\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x}^{3} \left( x-3 \right) -{x}^{3}-1/2\,{x}^{3}
 \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8 \right) \,{\rm d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x}^{3} \left( x-3 \right) \,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x
}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{x}^{3} \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8
 \right) \,{\rm d}x\\
&=-\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{3} \left( x-3 \right) \,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x
}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{x}^{3} \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8
 \right) \,{\rm d}x\\
&=-\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{4}-3\,{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x}^{3}
\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{x}^{3} \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8 \right) 
\,{\rm d}x\\
&=-\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{4}\,{\rm d}x-\int_{0}^{2}\!-3\,{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+
\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{x}^{3} \left( {x
}^{2}-6\,x+8 \right) \,{\rm d}x\\
&=-{\frac {32}{5}}-\int_{0}^{2}\!-3\,{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x
}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{x}^{3} \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8
 \right) \,{\rm d}x\\
&=-{\frac {32}{5}}+3\,\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x}
^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{x}^{3} \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8
 \right) \,{\rm d}x\\
&={\frac {28}{5}}+\int_{0}^{2}\!-{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{
x}^{3} \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8 \right) \,{\rm d}x\\
&={\frac {28}{5}}-\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{x
}^{3} \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8 \right) \,{\rm d}x\\
&=8/5+\int_{0}^{2}\!-1/2\,{x}^{3} \left( {x}^{2}-6\,x+8 \right) 
\,{\rm d}x\\
&=8/5-1/2\,\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{5}-6\,{x}^{4}+8\,{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=8/5-1/2\,\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{5}\,{\rm d}x-1/2\,\int_{0}^{2}\!-6\,{x}^{4
}\,{\rm d}x-1/2\,\int_{0}^{2}\!8\,{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=-{\frac {56}{15}}-1/2\,\int_{0}^{2}\!-6\,{x}^{4}\,{\rm d}x-1/2\,\int_{0
}^{2}\!8\,{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=-{\frac {56}{15}}+3\,\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{4}\,{\rm d}x-1/2\,\int_{0}^{2}
\!8\,{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x\\
&={\frac {232}{15}}-1/2\,\int_{0}^{2}\!8\,{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x\\
&={\frac {232}{15}}-4\,\int_{0}^{2}\!{x}^{3}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=-8/15
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Given your domain, let's first make a small correction:
\begin{align}
R &= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x\leq 2, x \leq y \leq 3x-x^2 \wedge 2  \right\} \\
&= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x\leq 1, x \leq y \leq 3x-x^2   \right\} \\
&\qquad\cup \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 1 < x \leq 2, x \leq y \leq 2   \right\}
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
I
&= \int_R x^2 - xy \;\mathrm{d}A\\
& = \int_0^2 \int_x^{3x-x^2 \wedge 2} x^2 - xy \;\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x \\
%
%
&= \int_0^1 \int_x^{3x-x^2} x^2 - xy \;\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x +
   \int_1^2 \int_x^{2} x^2 - xy      \;\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x \\
%
%
&= \int_0^1 x \left[x y - \frac{y^2}{2} \right]_{x}^{3 x-x^2} \;\mathrm{d}x +
   \int_1^2 x \left[x y - \frac{y^2}{2} \right]_{x}^{2}       \; \mathrm{d}x \\
%
%
&= \int_0^1 \left(- 2 x^3 + 2 x^4 -\frac{x^5}{2} \right) \;\mathrm{d}x +
   \int_1^2 \left(-2 x +2 x^2 -\frac{x^3}{2}  \right)   \;\mathrm{d}x \\
%
%
&= \left[-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{2 x^5}{5}-\frac{x^6}{12} \right]_0^1 +
   \left[-x+\frac{2 x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{8} \right]_1^2 \\
%
%
&= \left(-\frac{11}{60} \right) +\left(-\frac{5}{24}\right)\\
%
%
&= -\frac{47}{120}
\end{align}

Comment: To complement, $a \wedge b = \min(a,b)$